# I am using MEAN, Displaying selected ( from browser) log files from the linux server using node js.

Tags: angular, typescript, mean-stack

I am using angular HTTP get method to read logs from express server, store it in a variable and display in browser.

My problem is when I use response type as text, entire log file is formatted as single line, Please help me to fix this.

```
getData(server,value) {
  this.http.get(this.url/server/value, { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(res => {
    this.data = res;
  });
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `{ responseType: 'text' }` in the first place?

Comment: How can you tell it's formatted as a single line? How are you displaying the value?

Comment: How is the server sending back the response? Is it a `json`. How do you intend to show it on your UI?

Comment: I am using to node js to filter the logs(using the time stamp in the logs). Using angular I am giving option to choose time frame as parameter (last 2 hours, between hh;mm to hh:mm). Depends on the option it will pass the parameter and execute the script in the linux server using ssh utils ,display using express and I am getting the output "responseType: 'text'", which is displaying as single line instead of the proper logs....

Answer (score 0):

Use responseType: 'text' as 'text' or 'text as 'json'...for more information how non-json data work you may visit [Requesting non-JSON data](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data)